# User Profile Sync (on prem 2013) with no mysites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, user-profile-service, mysite

Strange request here. Let me explain what I'm hoping to accomplish and hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction.

Brand new 2013 on prem environment. All of our work flows and work will be done on the on prem environment. We will utilize the cloud for document storage.

My primary goal is to have user profile service/sync deployed without having mysites or any social features available on prem.

This is not to say we won't use those from the cloud but not right off the bat.

1. What is the best practice to deploy UPS without mysites?
2. Is that even possible?
3. Would it be better to deploy UPS (on prem) with Mysites (cloud) right away?

Any help or guidance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can disable MySite creation permission. It is easy, refer to [this](http://wellytonian.com/2012/10/restricting-permissions-on-mysites-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to configure MySites with the UPSA, although I'd recommend still creating a MySite host for users to be redirected to when they click on a name, etc. for additional profile information.

If you already have SPO, it might be best to set up ODfB hybrid now. It's a fairly simple task to undertake.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure UserProfileService as in the picture below. This will mostly remove/hide MySite-Integration, even if you have deployed and configured a MySite-Host in your environment.

[image: UPSConfiguration]

OneDrive, Newsfeed, FollowedSites and MySite links are gone
[image: OneDrive, Newsfeed, FollowedSites and MySite links are gone]